# where to store localhost sites acording to standards (ubuntu-server)?

Tags: nginx, webserver, standards

I want to know where is the best place to store the sites my ubuntu-server hosts acording to standards.

**I know** that by default, i can found it on /var/www directory, but I want to know if there is an standard about that.

Thanks for checking my question.

I did a search on google, but didn't find anything.

Comment: what do you mean by `best place`?

Comment: what do you mean by `localhost sites`?

Comment: By *best place* I mean directory
By localhost sites I mean sites I host on my PC, eg: site1.com, site2.com ..... Those sites (html, JS, php...) Files are stored in my PC.